# Lenovo T540p undocking triggers logout

Tags: laptop, lenovo, docking

I recently got a new Lenovo T540p with corresponding docking station and installed Ubuntu 14.04 (and later 15.10 with the same problem) on it.

The problem is that whenever I release the laptop from the docking station it automatically logs out. I've seen no options anywhere to disable this behaviour and numerous google searches came up with no solutions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.